# .animate not working in Firefox (.css does though)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-animate

Okay, so far this works in Chrome, but not Firefox.  It's pretty simple so I'm not sure what's going on.  If I change `.animate` to `.css` it works perfectly (minus the animation).

```
$("#superfish-1 > li").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({"border-left" : "3px solid #A5D572", "margin-left" : "-2px"}, "fast");
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({"border-left" : "1px solid #EFEFEF", "margin-left" : "0px"}, "fast");
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in the JavaScript console for any errors?

Comment: Yes. There aren't any errors and the css is not being modified at all.

Comment: you can not animate color and border type by default with jquery. unless you use some plugin i would recommend that you only animate the border-width.

Comment: Then why does it work in Chrome?

Comment: In theory, I could just css change the color and then animate the width with no issues, right?

Comment: I have tested it in chrome, it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/meo/Gsqre/1/ (i think you may do the animation in CSS3 also, and you are using ff3.5 or something like this)

Comment: Works fine on my website in Chrome. I'm uploading, will be up in a second.

Comment: Border does not change, margin does: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/S74hk/

Comment: anyway i posted a version that works as Answer, if the colors changes in your version its not because of the jquery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is how you do it.  You must `css` the border-color first and then animate the width:

Make sure you use the borderWidth or borderLeftWidth property (without quotes) otherwise it does't work for some reason.

```
$("#superfish-1 > li").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({"border-left" : "1px solid #A5D572"}).animate({borderLeftWidth : "3px", "margin-left" : "-2px"}, "fast");
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({borderLeftWidth : "1px", "margin-left" : "0px"}, "fast").css({"border-left" : "1px solid #EFEFEF"});
});
```

Comment: Of course it works with the quotes: http://jsfiddle.net/meo/vQgsP/ borderLeftWidth is just a alternate version to write it because "-" is an invalid character in a object property unless it is used with the quotes. You should down-vote your own answer :)

Comment: I used it with the quotes and it still didn't work.  Believe me meo, I know what I'm doing, I just didn't realize that you couldn't change the color in `.animate` because it worked in Chrome.  It's pretty childish that you voted down my answer, too.

Comment: no you don't know what you are doing. You question and your answer prove it. By the way it was not me that down-voted you.

Comment: Not my downvote either. Meo, your answer is just one way to achieve the goal. You don't have to `.css` the border colour - you can also, for instance, use a plugin to animate the colours and leave your initial code as is. The way you get confused with the JSON data format and how you alternate between Javascript-style and CSS-style property names make it hard to believe you really know what you're doing. Meo's fiddle works perfectly, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

The second parametre to the hover() function should be the `animate()` function as well, not `css()`. If `css()` is meant to be there, remove its second parametre (`"fast"`).

Comment: Sorry, I had just been testing, it was animate before. I'll fix that now.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the problem.  It's just a simple syntax error. It should be placed in the comments, not as an answer.

Comment: Let's see. You have a problem: a function doesn't work. I point out that there's a syntax error and therefore it can't work. And look, it's not an answer because it's about a syntax error! Great reasoning.

Comment: @Switz: a syntax error is still an _error_. If you ask a question and someone finds the solution, be it a syntax error or otherwise, it's still a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can not animate color and border type by default with jquery. unless you use some plugin i would recommend that you only animate the border-width.

as mentioned by @mingos you should remove the fast parameter in the css function to.

http://jsfiddle.net/meo/Gsqre/1/

tested in Chrome. Color does not animate.

This version animates the with and the margin and it works in all browsers:

```
$("#superfish-1 > li").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({"border-left-width" : "3px", "margin-left" : "-2px"}, "fast");
}, function() {
    $(this).css({"border-left-width" : "1px", "margin-left" : 0});
});
```

You can change the color separately in the css if you wish, even animate it. Or do the whole animation in CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/meo/Gsqre/3/

Comment: While I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question and look for a solution, this does not solve my problem.  There is a solution that works (all the way down to IE6 in fact).  Look above.

Comment: @Switz, you really should work on appreciating the effort others take to help you. Just because an answer doesn't solve your issue doesn't mean it qualifies for downvoting. It's neither misleading nor offers any false information. If you don't like it, just leave it alone instead of marking it as rubbish. Plus, your solution is based on this info (colours cannot be animated without a proper plugin), so I really think you should actually UPVOTE this answer.

Comment: @Switz: your example was not functional at all before you edited your question. So i think this is the best i could do. You should consider taking more time and effort to write proper questions so users can give you proper Answers. Or you can do what you have done on this question: Posting a vague question, getting hints from other answers, down-voting them and response to your own question :)

Comment: The question I asked was very clear cut and basic.  It was one small syntax error and that's not the problem here.  In your solution, the border color does not change.  In my solution it does.  That's what I wanted it to do.  I'm not here to be a dick and not give you credit, but you didn't give me the answer that solved my problem.  I'm sorry.

Comment: @Switz, in case you don't know what downvotes are for: they're for marking answers as misleading or otherwise offering information that is false. Meo's answer was a partial solution. Plus, your question indeed is asked in a rather vague way. The syntax error you'd accidentally left in only indicates how little attention you've put to actually asking a good question, and therefore to the people answering it.